# Configuring FastJMX and collected

Tags: java, plugins, amazon-cloudwatch, collectd

I'm trying to set FastJMX plugin for collected but with no success. I found this thread in github
https://github.com/rahulaga/collectd-fast-jmx#readme

but I can't figure out how to install the thing, how can I get "fast-jmx jar" file, from where?
I installed GenericJMX with yum but when I try it for FastJMX I get "No package collectd-fast-jmx available." so I guess this is not the way... There are a bunch of files/folders in the repo but I have no idea what to do with them. I'm noob. Can somebody explain?!

Ultimately I want to send this metrics to cloudwatch

Comment: The repo contains a pom.xml which is a maven build file. For further info you can search for "build maven project"